# Pagination in Clojure

Tags: clojure, pagination, will-paginate, noir, hiccup

Is there anything equivalent to will_paginate for noir/hiccup?

How do people usually paginate with noir/hiccup?

Thank you

Comment: Is your second question separated from the first? I write Clojure bots that write .csv and small report files. I paginate by trial and error using `spit`, but I believe your question is really focused on is their a Clojure equivalent to will_paginate.

Comment: yes. you are right. It is quite focused on the first question.

Comment: Here was my go at it : http://blog.fzakaria.com/2015/07/26/pagination-in-clojure/

Answer (score 4):

No as far as I know. But here is a great [blog post](http://www.flyingmachinestudios.com/programming/dissecting-gratefulplace/) with examples of how can be done.